# How to unpack a .zip file with Lua?

Tags: lua, zip, extract

How do you extract a .zip file with multiple subdirectories in Lua?

Yes, I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829175/how-to-extract-files-from-a-zip-file-using-lua), but I don't think it works with multiple subdirectories.
I don`t see any function in LuaZip that would allow listing files in a directory inside the zip file.
Any suggestsions?

I don`t know the directories' (those inside the zip) name, so I need to list them somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you open a zip with `zfile = zip.open('file.zip')`, scan it with `for member in zfile:files()`. `member` will contain full path of files inside zip, including all leading directories, separated with `/`. It is up to you to parse it, create directories in real filesystem and extract files to correct place.

If you need list of unique directories, just strip file name from all members and save remaining directories as keys to table.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that zfile:files() also gives me all the files inside subdirectories.