# Reading data file (compressed in .rar with password) in lua

Tags: lua, compression

How can I read a file that is compressed inside a `.rar` archive (with password-protection, I have the password)?

The main function i use to read the datafile is:

```
if not g_resources.addSearchPath(g_resources.getWorkDir() .. "data", true) then
  g_logger.fatal("Unable to add data directory to the search path.")  
end
```

This funcion reads it perfectly, but when I try:

```
g_resources.getWorkDir() .. "data.rar/data", true)
```

it stops to work.

Comment: Maybe you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829175/how-to-extract-files-from-a-zip-file-using-lua) SO question.

Comment: Well... Thanks for your comments, I already read it, I tried use the function, but not worked... maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: Fixed formatting and some grammar, removed "thanks". IMO the question is still not clear, lacking code and an actual description of the problem. Please see [mcve].